# Solving full anagrams with a dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm, constraint-programming, anagram

I am solving a classical problem. To be precise, I am trying to solve a full anagram.

Any word or phrase that exactly reproduces the letters in another order is an anagram.

I have an anagram, a dictionary and a hash. I need to come up with the phrase which has been originally hashed, so a program should generate all permutations using given dictionary and check whether anyy of those is the answer.

All in all, someone hid a message for me and I need to crack it!

sample input:

> scofriybaarae dict.txt FD8D80332CCA32905F11860FB866CA92

All phrases below are valid anagram of *scofriybaarae* so the words they consist of may be different or in different order.

*are frisco a bay*

*frisco area bay*

*frisco bay area*

However only the last one is the answer. This is because MD5 of *frisco bay area* match with the MD5 given as a parameter.

We can split up the task on processing the dictionary, generating combinations and checking md5.

I use tree of letters, some nodes of that tree may indicate and of the word. End of a branch is always end of a word. This means that a single branch can represent many words e.g. bold letters indicate completeness

> ai**r**por**t**

In the example above two words are stored, so it is easy to cross-out used letters when you walk through.

My program can build up a tree from a dictionary pretty fast though I am not happy with the performance of the solver.

The problem I identified is just an enormous number of combinations which I do not know how to alleviate. For instance, given 13 letters and a number of dictionary words ranging by length from one to 13. In this case there is 6227020800 combinations of one-letter words and you can imagine how many more combinations there may be.

I noticed that the more shorter words I put the slower it gets.

I am wondering if I am on the right track or it is just conceptually wrong?

Should I employ a database engine?

There is a chunk of my dictionary for your convenience:

> bay ara area aera fbaer frisco friscob friscoba afriscoar friscobay
>   bayfrisco aabceforsy

```
package margana;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Solution {

    private final String givenLetterSet;
    private String file;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

    LetterNode root = new LetterNode('\u03A9', null); // omega root node
    private Map<Character, Long> countedOriginalLetters = new HashMap<Character, Long>();

    /**
     * Mixed Anatree class
     */
    public static class LetterNode implements Comparable<LetterNode> {
        private final char letter;// does not matter for the root node
        private boolean ending;
        private Map<Character, LetterNode> leaves = new HashMap<Character, LetterNode>();
        private LetterNode motherNode;
        private String wholeCachedWord;
        private int length = 1;

        public LetterNode(char oneLetter, LetterNode mom) {
            letter = oneLetter;
            if (mom != null) {
                if (mom.motherNode != null) {
                    length += mom.length;// all consecutive nodes minus mom length
                }
                motherNode = mom;
            }
        }

        public char getLetter() {
            return letter;
        }

        public Character getCharacter() {
            return Character.valueOf(letter);
        }

        public boolean isEnding() {
            return ending;
        }

        public void setEnding(boolean ending) {
            this.ending = ending;
        }

        public Map<Character, LetterNode> getLeaves() {
            return leaves;
        }

        public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }

        public LetterNode getMotherNode() {
            return motherNode;
        }

        public String compileNodesIntoWord() {
            if (wholeCachedWord != null) {
                return wholeCachedWord;
            }
            LetterNode node = motherNode;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
            buffer.append(letter);
            while (node.motherNode != null) {
                buffer.insert(0, node.letter);
                if (node.motherNode.motherNode == null) {
                    break;
                }
                node = node.motherNode;
            }
            wholeCachedWord = buffer.toString();
            return wholeCachedWord;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            LetterNode that = (LetterNode) o;
            if (letter != that.letter) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (int) letter;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(LetterNode o) {
            return Character.compare(letter, o.letter);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (ending) {
                return compileNodesIntoWord();
            }
            return String.valueOf(letter);
        }
    }

    public Solution(String anagram, String dictionaryFile) {
        file = dictionaryFile;
        byte[] tempArray = anagram.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "").getBytes();
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        givenLetterSet = new String(tempArray);
        for (char oneChar : anagram.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            Long numberOfOccurrences = countedOriginalLetters.get(Character.valueOf(oneChar));
            if (numberOfOccurrences == null) {
                countedOriginalLetters.put(new Character(oneChar), new Long(1));
            } else {
                countedOriginalLetters.put(new Character(oneChar), new Long(numberOfOccurrences.longValue() + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rule out rubbish words
     *
     * @param oneWord
     * @return
     */
    private boolean invalidAgainstGivenSentence(String oneWord) {
        if (oneWord.length() > givenLetterSet.length()) {
            return true;
        }
        for (char oneChar : oneWord.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
/*            if (oneChar == "'".charAt(0)) {// to regards ' as a letter
                continue;
            }*/
            Long amountOfParticularLetter = countedOriginalLetters.get(Character.valueOf(oneChar));
            if (amountOfParticularLetter == null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void growTree() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String oneWord;
        long depth = 0; // for fun
        long candidate = 0;
        boolean isNewWord = false;
        while ((oneWord = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (invalidAgainstGivenSentence(oneWord)) {
                continue;//is not a valid chunk of the given anagram
            }
            LetterNode previousNode = root;
            isNewWord = false;
            for (char one : oneWord.toCharArray()) {
                LetterNode currentLetter = previousNode.getLeaves().get(Character.valueOf(one));
                if (currentLetter == null) {// letter does not exists, let us add it
                    LetterNode newNode = new LetterNode(one, previousNode);
                    previousNode.getLeaves().put(Character.valueOf(one), newNode);
                    currentLetter = newNode;
                    isNewWord = true;
                }
                previousNode = currentLetter;
            }
            if (isNewWord) {
                candidate += 1;
            }
            previousNode.setEnding(true);
            depth = Math.max(depth, previousNode.getLength());
        }
        System.out.println("Created an anatree comprising of " + candidate + " words, and " + depth + " levels");
        br.close();
    }

    public void solve(String md5) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        List<LetterNode> foundWords = new ArrayList<LetterNode>();
        LinkedList<Character> input = new LinkedList<Character>();
        Set<Character> inputSet = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (Character one : givenLetterSet.toCharArray()) {
            input.add(one);
            inputSet.add(one);
        }
        NavigableSet<LetterNode> firstLevel = new TreeSet(root.getLeaves().values()).descendingSet();
        for (LetterNode node: firstLevel) {
            if (inputSet.contains(node.getCharacter())) {
                executorService.execute(new SolverRunnable(foundWords, input, node, md5.toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    class SolverRunnable implements Runnable {
        private List<LetterNode> initialWords;
        private List<Character> spareCharacters;
        private LetterNode initialNode;
        private String md5Hash;

        public SolverRunnable(List<LetterNode> foundWords, List<Character> spareLetters, LetterNode route, String md5) {
            initialNode = route;
            initialWords = foundWords;
            spareCharacters = spareLetters;
            md5Hash = md5;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Started solving branch '" + initialNode.getCharacter() + "' from root ");
            try {
                solve(initialWords, spareCharacters, initialNode, md5Hash);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void solve(List<LetterNode> foundWords, List<Character> spareLetters, LetterNode route, String md5) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        List<LetterNode> localFoundWords = new ArrayList<LetterNode>(foundWords);
        List<Character> workspace = new LinkedList<Character>();
        LetterNode current = route;
        workspace.addAll(spareLetters);
        while (!current.getLeaves().isEmpty()) {
            if (!workspace.contains(current.getCharacter())) {
                break;
            }
            workspace.remove(current.getCharacter());
            if (current.getLeaves().size() > 1) {// start solving recursively then quit
                for (LetterNode node: new TreeSet<LetterNode>(current.getLeaves().values())) {//checking every branch
                    if (workspace.contains(node.getCharacter())) {
                        solve(localFoundWords, workspace, node, md5);
                    }
                }
                break;//we solve routes without forks
            }
            if (workspace.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            if (current.isEnding()) {//recursively solving a shorter word first then continue
                localFoundWords.add(current);
                startOver(workspace, localFoundWords, md5);
                localFoundWords.remove(current);
            }
            current = (LetterNode) current.getLeaves().values().toArray()[0];
        }
        if (current.isEnding()) {
            localFoundWords.add(current);
            workspace.remove(current.getCharacter());
            if (workspace.isEmpty()) {
                check(localFoundWords, md5);
                return;
            }
            startOver(workspace, localFoundWords, md5);
        }
    }

    private void check(List<LetterNode> localFoundWords, String md5) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (isPreliminaryValid(localFoundWords)) {
            String phrase = concatenateNodesWithSpaces(localFoundWords);
            if (md5.equalsIgnoreCase(digest(phrase))) {
                System.out.println(phrase);
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startOver(List<Character> workspace, List<LetterNode> localFoundWords, String md5) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        for (LetterNode node: root.getLeaves().values()) {
            if (workspace.contains(node.getCharacter())) {
                solve(localFoundWords, workspace, node, md5);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isPreliminaryValid(List<LetterNode> words) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int total = 0;
        for (LetterNode word : words) {
            builder.append(word.compileNodesIntoWord());
            total += word.length;
        }
        if (total != givenLetterSet.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        char[] letters = builder.toString().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(letters);
        return new String(letters).equals(givenLetterSet);
    }

    public static String concatenateNodesWithSpaces(List<LetterNode> words) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int spaces = words.size() - 1;
        for (LetterNode word : words) {
            builder.append(word.compileNodesIntoWord());
            if (spaces > 0) {
                spaces--;
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static String digest(String original) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(original.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(34);
        for (byte b : md.digest()) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Solution s = new Solution(args[0], args[1]);
        s.growTree();
/*
        s.solve("BE2B1B1409746B5416F44FB6D9C16A55");// cop pop
        //s.solve("493DF2D8AC7EDB14CD50CA07A539A805");// cop p'op
*/
        s.solve(args[2]); //frisco bay area
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what this problem is. Can you present some sample input and output? I'm not clear about what the hash has to do with this. Are you simply trying to solve an anagram?

Comment: It might be quicker to ignore your anagram completely (except for length) and simply create combinations of the words in your dictionary until you get a matching hash.

Comment: Please check my update of the question.

Comment: In the problem, can it be any anagram or does the resulting phrase consist of `proper` words seperated by a space? Your dictionary seems to consist of allot of junk words like 'aabceforsy' and `afriscoar`. Take those out and you reduce the problem space. You could also weigh your dictionary such that common words come first.

Comment: We should regard proper everything that has equal or smaller amount of the same letters. The point is we do not know what was ciphered originally, so all words are legal.

Comment: Theoretically, the hidden phrase may be "I l o v e y o u" meaning that only sigle letter words are used.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (nodejs):

```
var
  md5 = require('MD5'),
  fs = require('fs');

function createIndex(str) {
  var i, index = {}, chr;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chr = str[i];
    index[chr] = (index[chr] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return index;
}

function indexContains(index, subIndex) {
  var chr;
  for (chr in subIndex) {
    if (subIndex.hasOwnProperty(chr) && (!index.hasOwnProperty(chr) || subIndex[chr] > index[chr])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function excludeIndex(index, subIndex) {
  var newIndex = {}, chr, value, empty = true;
  for (chr in index) {
    if (index.hasOwnProperty(chr)) {
      value = index[chr];
      if (subIndex.hasOwnProperty(chr)) {
        value -= subIndex[chr];
      }
      if (value) {
        newIndex[chr] = value;
        empty = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return empty ? null : newIndex;
}

function uniqueByProperty(items, property) {
  return items.filter(function (item, index) {
    var i, value = item[property];
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      if (items[i][property] === value) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}

function findAnagram(charsIndex, dict, prevWords, targetHash) {
  var i, item, nextCharsIndex, result, words;  
  dict = dict.filter(function (item) {
    return indexContains(charsIndex, item.index);
  });  
  if (!prevWords.length) {    
    dict = uniqueByProperty(dict, 'word');
  }  
  for (i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
    item = dict[i];
    nextCharsIndex = excludeIndex(charsIndex, item.index);
    words = prevWords.concat(item.word);
    if (nextCharsIndex) {
      result = findAnagram(nextCharsIndex, dict, words, targetHash);
      if (result) {
        return result;
      }
    } else {
      result = words.join(' ');
      if (md5(result) === targetHash) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

var      
  dict = fs.readFileSync('./data/wordlist.txt', 'utf8').split('\n')
    .filter(function (str) {
      return str.replace(/ /, '');
    })
    .map(function (word) {
      return {word: word, index: createIndex(word)};
    }),
  initialStr = "poultry outwits ants",
  finalMD5 = "4624d200580677270a54ccff86b9610e",    
  result = findAnagram(createIndex(initialStr.replace(/ /, '')), dict, [], finalMD5); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good, thanks for publishing. You already aware about apostrophe.

Comment: In fact, one can operate with position independent hashes like the one based on Prime Numbers. Each word may be represented as a sum of its letters. The beauty of that approach is that product is always not a Prime Number. As for the data structure, one may build up a tree or graph of sums then run through looking for the route producing original hash sum.